# Retrieve unique ID from MongoDB using Express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm fairly new to MongoDB. My current code is as follows:

```
var app = express();
app.post('/myDB', function(req, res) {
console.log('POSTed data');
db.myDB.insert(req.body, function(err, doc) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json(doc);
});
```

})

I know that when data is inserted into MongoDB, a unique _id key:value pair is created. I would like to have access to this unique id upon data insertion.

But from what I know currently (admittedly not a whole lot), I would have to do an app.get('/myDB/:id')... (Or something similar) in order to access that unique identifier. Is there a way to do this without having to make an extra http request?

Comment: You can use db.collection.save() to retrieve the inserted document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB, with the Node.js driver, you can get the **[inserted id](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html)** from the callback function's second parameter. The syntax is:

```
collection.insert(docs[[, options], callback])
```

where `docs` is a single document object or an array of documents, `options` is an options object and `callback` is a callback function to run after the record is inserted. The second paramter returns an array of documents inserted.

Thus you can retrieve the inserted id this way:

```
var app = express();
app.post('/myDB', function(req, res) {
console.log('POSTed data');
db.myDB.insert(req.body, {w:1}, function(err, doc) {
    console.log("Record added as "+ doc[0]._id);
    res.json(doc);
});
```

You can read more on the docs **[here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#insert)**.